# Apollo cache - JSON blob - SQL server; will setup work?

Tags: json, graphql, apollo

The backend (SQL server) I'm using cannot be made GraphQL ready (long story short - politics!) whereas frontend relies on GraphQL. I can however read/write a JSON blob. The JSON is 400kb (small) and normalized.

To go around this I intend to use Apollo cache, providing GraphQL interface to frontend. App would fetch JSON from SQL and load to cache.

If any mutations done, user will manually trigger action to save data from cache as JSON and replace blob in SQL.

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work? Or are there better ways?

Comment: Apologies for a question on your question, byt is there a way one could make SQL Server GraphQL ready if politics were not an issue? I have seen some limited SQL Server libraries but no examples of a full GraphQL interfact for that database.

Comment: I'm not the sql expert to answer that but in my case I simply don't have any authority to access anything behind SQL walls. Even outside I can only accsess by webmethods. Even if - GraphQl implementations would have to happen inside my app then which I think would be awkard.